# What is the best way to periodically export a counter from a loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have created a daemon in Ruby which has a counter incrementing inside of a loop.  The loop does its business, then sleeps for 1 second, then continues. Simplified it's something like:

```
loop do
  response = send_command
  if response == 1
    counter += 1
  end
  sleep(1)
end
```

Every 5 minutes I would like to call a method to database the counter value.  I figure there are a few ways to do this.  The initial way I considered was calling Time.now in the loop, examining it to match 5 minutes, 0 seconds, and if that matched, call the sql function.  That seems terribly inefficient, however, and it could also miss a record if send_command took some time.

Another possibility may be to make available the counter variable, which could be called (and reset) via a socket.  I briefly took a look at the Socket class, and that seems possible.

Is there an obvious/best way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to save every 5 minutes, you could just use a Thread. Something like:

```
Thread.new do
    save_value_in_the_db(counter)
    sleep 5*60
end
```

Note that the thread have access to counter if it is defined in the same block as the loop. you could also use an object and have the @counter declared insidd.

If you prefer to access remotely, you can do it with a socket or use a drb approach, that is probably easier. This drb tutorial seem to fit your requirements: http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/drb.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to update the counter more frequently than every 5 minutes.  It's a digital reading changing from 0 to 1 - I have to count changes, and many may occur in the 5 minute segment.  I've done some drb, it just seemed more than was necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer.  This is a decent option as well - and one I'll consider.

Comment: This is what I wound up doing.  I went global on the counter(s) and created two threads - one to collect the data and one to database.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have the counter be updated every time through the loop, then periodically have something read that and update the database.

That makes a simpler main loop because it doesn't have to pay attention to how long it's needed to wait before exporting the value.

And, it's very common and normal to have a periodic task that samples a value and does something with it.

Creating a simple socket would work well. Ruby's [Socket](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html) code RDoc has some samples for echo servers that might get you started.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's where I was planning to go anyway.  I just didn't know if there was an easier way to do it.  I may be able to socketize my other monitors as well and offload the databasing to a single app.  Thanks for the confirmation.